# for loop in groovy for string with concatenation

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

I have string like `Color=Blue|Size=M|Style=simpleStyle` and it need to be converted as like below by using groovy.

```
<Item>
      <comp>
        <name>Color</name>
        <value>Blue</value>
      </comp>
      <comp>
        <name>Size</name>
        <value>M</value>
      </comp>
      <comp>
        <name>Style</name>
        <value>simpleStyle</value>
      </comp>
</Item>
```

I have written groovy for loop something like below. I believe i am trying it in bit harder way. Is there any simple way to produce above XML using Groovy ?

```
for (int i = 0; StrRelationshipDetails.toString().contains('|'); i++) {
    println StrRelationshipDetails.toString()

    def StrPair = new StringBuilder(StrRelationshipDetails.substring(0, StrRelationshipDetails.indexOf('|')))
    def StrName = new StringBuilder(StrPair.substring(0, StrPair.indexOf('=')))
    def StrValue = new StringBuilder(StrPair.substring(StrPair.indexOf('=')+1, StrPair.size()))

    StrRelationshipDetails = StrRelationshipDetails.substring(StrRelationshipDetails.indexOf('|')+1, StrRelationshipDetails.size())
}
    println StrRelationshipDetails.toString()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way (a Groovy one) should work without the use of `for` loop:

```
String provided = "Color=Blue|Size=M|Style=simpleStyle"

def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder()

builder.Item {
    provided.tokenize('|')*.tokenize('=').each { element ->
        comp {
            name element[0]
            value element[1]
        }
    }
}

return
```

results in

```
<Item>
  <comp>
    <name>Color</name>
    <value>Blue</value>
  </comp>
  <comp>
    <name>Size</name>
    <value>M</value>
  </comp>
  <comp>
    <name>Style</name>
    <value>simpleStyle</value>
  </comp>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
def result = "<Item>"
def values = StrRelationshipDetails.toString().tokenize("|")
for(def kv of values) {
    result +="<comp>"
    def pair = kv.tokenize("=")
    def name = pair[0]
    def value= pair[1]
    result += "<name>$name</name>" 
    result += "<value>$value</value>" 
    result +="</comp>"
}
result +="</Item>"
```

Then I would use [XMLSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) to make it into an XML doc.

Something I need to note. The code above is very descriptive to make things more clear. It can be way shorter (especially with Groovy). You can also define the `def` variables as `String`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am beginner for groovy script. I have received compilation error as like below. 
`Script8.groovy: 12: unexpected token: def @ line 12, column 5.
   for(def kv of values) {`

Comment: It seems groovy is not allowing me to use def inside for loop braces.

Comment: @Simbu yeah, sorry I was just coding JS and Python for 8h and mixed everything.

Try `for (kv in values)`

Comment: @Simbu @nathan-hughes solution is quite Groovy.

 Read more about collect entries here http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#collectEntries(java.util.Map, groovy.lang.Closure)

Think of it as similar to `map`